# What is the ruby expression "%.1f" and how does this round a decimal?

Tags: ruby, floating-point, decimal, rounding

I want to round a float with many decimal places, such as `2.638232371` down to one decimal place, such as `2.6`.

I found this will do so:

```
"%.2f" % 1.93213
#=> 1.93
```

But what is "%.2f"? and is the result a string? I'd just like to understand how this works.

Comment: Please read doc `Kernel#sprintf`

Comment: The precision can be variable, BTW. Try this: `sprintf('%.*f', 5, Math::PI)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the format string used by [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf).

The syntax of a format string is:

```
%[flags][width][.precision]type
```

`%.2f` means to use the floating-point format with 2 digits of precision.

Comment: 'Kernal' -> 'Kernel' ?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Typo, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in irb and see for yourself whether or not the result is a String:

```
result = "%.2f" % 1.93213
result.class
```

As for what "%.2f" means, check out the [sprintf](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) docs

Comment: `$ irb`
`irb(main):001:0> result = "%.2f" % 1.93213`
`=> "1.93"`
`irb(main):002:0> result.class`
`=> String`